# Métodos Patch com Route e Authorize - webApi

Tags: c#, http-request, asp.net-web-api-2

Estou montando um projeto com webApi2 utilizando OAuth.

O sistema tem (por exemplo) cadastro de Usuários (padrão), com permissões de Visualizar, Editar, Novo, Ativar, Inativar, Excluir.

Os métodos padrão de `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, estão OK, porém para fazer as outras funcionalidades posso utilizar um `POST` com rotas (que apenas mudam o status do objeto):

```
[Route("api/usuario/{id}/ativar"), Authorize(Roles = "usuario.ativar")]

public HttpResponseMessage Ativar(int id) { ... }

[Route("api/usuario/{id}/inativar"), Authorize(Roles = "usuario.inativar")]

public HttpResponseMessage Inativar(int id) { ... }
```

Utilizando `HttpPatch`, não consegui uma forma de atualizar o status do obj apenas no método autorizado, pois posso passar para a chamada {Status: Inativo}, sendo que o usuário atual só tem permissão de visualizar, e se passar outras propriedades, elas também serão atalizadas (requisição via AngularJS).

Haveria uma forma de utilizar isto com `HttpPatch`? Porém preciso deixar habilitado ao usuário apenas o que o mesmo tem permissão. Ou neste meu caso o que supriria minha necessidade seria apenas utilizar `POST` e criar métodos específicos com permissões e rotas?

Comment: Você está usando o que pra testar o `PUT`? O navegador ou alguma ferramenta?

Comment: O próprio navegador. Está tudo funcionando. A dúvida é de qual a melhor forma de implementar ações diferentes das padrões (PUT,POST,GET), no caso Ativar/Inativar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já me frustrei com essa dúvida também: preciso fazer alguma coisa específica mas não cabe o `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, ou até mesmo o `PATCH`.

Minha resposta? Use o `POST`, com as rotas apropriadas. Essa, creio eu, é uma forma simples mas eficaz.

Podemos passar horas e horas discutindo qual verbo HTTP cabe a *Ativar*, mas acho que no final do dia, `POST` é o mais apropriado.

Comment: Certo, entendi. Se não fosse um projeto dependendo de permissões, poderia até fazer em um método PATCH para atualização, pois o usuário poderia efetuar qualquer alteração.

Answer (score 0):

Esta não é a maneira correta de testar. [Navegadores HTML não suportam `PUT` nem `DELETE`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms).

[Utilize uma ferramenta mais adequada para seus testes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo), reimplemente `[HttpPut]` e repita o teste. `PATCH` seria o mais adequado para seu caso, já que `PUT` tem o objetivo de [substituir o objeto por completo se ele não existir](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/), semanticamente falando.